# How to get directory of selected file?

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, openfiledialog

I have a program where a user selects a file with an OpenFileDialog, I store that path (ofd.FileName) into a string FilePath, I need to get the name of the folder that the file is in, how do I do that?

Like if user selects file "C:\Users\Name\Documents\hi.txt", how do I get the folder path "C:\Users\Name\Documents" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) offers numerous methods to handle File and Path strings
In your case you need to use

```
string fullFilePath = @"C:\Users\Name\Documents\hi.txt";
string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFilePath);
Console.WriteLine(pathOnly);
```

Comment: Testing this now, I think it's what I need.

Comment: Works perfect! Will accept when it lets me. Thank you! Excellent answer and quick response.